# How to calculate AUC(Area Under Curve) for voting ensemble classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, roc, voting, auc, ensemble-learning

For example, i have 3 thresholding classifiers c1,c2,c3 and 10 instances for binary classification(labeled 0/1), then i can get score matrix S of shape(10,3), S[i,j] is the score of i'th instance given by j'th classifier and when threshold is set, i can get the predicted labels by comparing the scores to the threshold.

Now i use the voting method for c1,c2,c3 ensemble. As far as i know, calculating the AUC value needs to the scores given by the voting ensemble classifier. However after voting, only the predicted labels is given by the ensemble classifier. How to calculate the AUC value in this case?

Answer (score 2):

As you said, AUC requires a threshold on the probability estimate. It does not matter how you created your model - if it is ensemlbe or not, all that matters is that you need a model outputing P(y|x). For regular ensemble (each member having the same weight) it is simply:

```
P(y|x) = 1/3 [ P1(y|x) + P2(y|x) + P3(y|x) ]
```

and this is what you apply thresholding to (and consequently ROC/AUC is based on it).

Comment: Thx for reply. the final P(y|x) is exactly what i need, but the formula you provide seems to be applied in averaging ensemble cases. If used for voting ensemble, we would get the same AUC value for both the averaging and voting ensemble, which is confusing me. How to understand this?

Comment: when you say "vote" how do you assign "votes"? There is no single method to do so. For example VotingClassifier in sklearn has two options - soft (the one I described) and hard, which will be very bad for things like ROC due to step-wise character, there you would have P(y=1|x) = #{k: argmax y Pk(y|x) = 1} / 3

Comment: It is the hard voting that i want to assign to. Well, it dose seem too difficult to calculate the AUC using P(y|x). Is there any other way to get AUC?

Comment: AUC is not a metric, AUC is literally the integral under some curve, but typically it is AUC of ROC curve, and you cannot compute ROC curve without P(y|x).